# Служебные алломорфы и варианты служебных морфем

Tags: морфемы

Знатоки!!! Помогите пожалуйста выделить в словах: сильнейший,  ближайший,  добрее,  тверже, высотой  , высотою  -     варианты служебных алломорф и варианты служебных морфем

Answer (score 1):

Служебные алломорфы -добрее- тверже, сильнейший - ближайший ((Потому что они обусловлены позицией после согласных определённого качества)
-ее (-ей) – от основ на согласный (кроме непроизводных основ на г, х, д, т, ст): светлый – светлее, слабый – слабее, прелестный – прелестнее, завистливый – завистливее;

-е – от непроизводных основ на г, х, д, т, ст: дорогой – дороже, сухой – суше, молодой – моложе, богатый – богаче, простой – проще– от прилагательных с суффиксом -к-, имеющих краткую форму мужского рода на -ок: короткий (короток) – короче, низкий (низок) – ниже, громкий (громок) – громче;

Образование форм с помощью -е- сопровождается чередованием согласных на конце основы: дорогой- дороже, громкий – громче, сухой – суше, дешёвый – дешевле.
);
-айш - после шипящих;
 Варианты служебных морфем - высотой - высотою, .(ой-ою- разница стилистическая,  , не обусловленная позицией).